# Comparing the value of template variable

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I'm writing a linked list for a C++ class and am stuck trying to figure out how to compare two generic typed nodes for a sorting algorithm. In Java I would just implement the Comparable interface and use the compareTo() method to determine which is "larger" or "smaller", letting the user of the Collection define this. Is there something similar in C++ that I can use? I know I can override the "<" operator but I don't know if this is the "best" method (subjective, I know; really just asking for pros and cons if there is another) to compare unknown types.

So, are there any other options to compare unknown types at runtime that seem to be more appropriate than overriding the "<" operator?

*EDIT:* Changed the operator I need to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather you have a list class template and you want to implement a `sort()` method on it. I would follow the example set by `std::list<T>` for this:

```
template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
    // ...
    template <typename Compare>
    void sort(Compare compare) {
        // use compare(x, y) to determine if x is smaller than y
    }
    void sort() { this->sort(std::less<T>()); }
};
```

That is, instead of making a fixed choice you would default to use `operator<()` but allow the user to use a different ordering predicate. As long as the comparison function implement a [strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) anything can be used.

Comment: You're right, I would need to override the '<' operator. I was mixing the equals() and compareTo() method in Java. I'm going to have to look into how this works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, overloading operators (for sorting, you'd use `operator<` and maybe `operator==`) is the way. It's idiomatic and you needn't mark the interface (like deriving from a specific interface), and it is not typically done.

   The good thing is that even if the user wanted to use some type without relation operators, he/she can extend their interface by providing free function overloads of the operators.
2. You could use any other method (such as inventing your own interface, eg. function `int T::cmp(...)` that would return 0/1/-1 depending on the relation of the parameters. However, this has the great disadvantage that you won't be able to reuse others' classes.
3. The STL uses a user-passed function object object to compare what it needs, which is needed to provide different sorting orders on the same data (say, ordering people by surname vs. by telephone number). If you don't need this (or are prepared to forgo this functionality), you can stick to using `operator<`.

Comment: Note that returning a tristate sounds like a bright idea but normally tends to result in slower performance when actually using the result. Using a Boolean result implementing a [strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) works better.